# I need my array to output in my main or test method and to implement polymorphism methods in a loop call

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

I can't output my shapes other than what I commented out. I am trying to find a way to output it in my shapes or test shapes classes. I will need to call a for loop and output some polymorphism methods. Will I need getters and setters for that?

public class Shapes{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Shapes [ ] Array = {
         new Triangle ( " ", " ", " "),
         new Rectangle ( " ", " ", " "),
         new Square ( " ", " ", " "), 
         new Ellipse ( " ", " ", " "),
         new Circle ( " ", " ", " ")};

    }


public void TestShapes ( ) {

    }
 }
public class Rectangle extends Shapes  {
 private String draw;
 private String erase;
 private String move;

public Rectangle ( ) {

    draw = " ";
    erase = " ";
    move = " ";
    System.out.println( " Default constructor" );

}

public Rectangle (String draw, String erase, String move ) {

    draw = " Rectangle - draw method\n";
    erase = " Rectangle - erase method\n";
    move = " Rectangle - move method\n";
    //System.out.println( draw + erase + move );

 }

}
public class Square extends Rectangle   {

  private String draw;
  private String erase;
  private String move;

public Square ( ) {

    draw = " ";
    erase = " ";
    move = " ";
    System.out.println( " Default constructor" );

}

public Square (String draw, String erase, String move ) {

    draw = " Square - draw method \n";
    erase = " Square - erase method  \n";
    move = " Square - move method\n";

   // System.out.println( draw + erase + move );
}


}
public class Ellipse extends Shapes    {

  private String draw;
  private String erase;
  private String move;

 public Ellipse ( ) {

    draw = " ";
    erase = " ";
    move = " ";
    System.out.println( " Default constructor" );
 }

 public Ellipse (String draw, String erase, String move ) {

    draw = "ellipse - draw method \n ";
    erase = "ellipse - erase method \n";
    move = "ellipse - move method \n";
   // System.out.println( draw + erase + move);

}

}
public class Circle extends Ellipse     {

  private String draw;
  private String erase;
  private String move;

public Circle ( ) {

    draw = " ";
    erase = " ";
    move = " ";
    System.out.println( "Default constructor " );
}

public Circle (String draw, String erase, String move) {

    draw = "Circle - draw method \n";
    erase = "Circle - erase method \n";
    move = "Circle - move method \n";
    //System.out.println( draw + erase + move );

}

} 
public class Triangle extends Shapes    {

  private String draw;
  private String erase;
  private String move;

public Triangle ( ) {

    draw = " ";
    erase = " ";
    move = " ";
    System.out.println( "Default constructor " );

}

public Triangle (String draw, String erase, String move ) {

    draw = " Triangle - draw method \n";
    erase = " Triangle - erase method \n";
    move = " Triangle -  move method \n";
   // System.out.println( draw + erase + move);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Way to Do it**
Every class has Object as a superclass. Thus, the toString() can be overridden
You should override the toString() method in all the different shapes that you want to create.

```
 public String toString()
{
   String s = "";
   s+= "draw " + this.draw;
   s+= "erase" + this.erase;
   s+= "move" + this.move;
   return s;
}
```

Then print by calling (This will print the info based on the overridden toString() method in the Square class)

```
 public void TestShapes (Shapes[] Array ) {
     for(int x =0; x<Array.length;x++)//iterates through array
       {
             System.out.println(Array[x].toString());
       }
    }
 }
```

Another problem you should be having is that Shapes cannot be accessed by the method. 
Thus, you should add a Shapes Array into the parameter like I did above

**Second Way to do it**
No matter what, you are looking to print a String. Thus, a method that has the same name but different implementation must return a String or print directly to the console

```
public void TestShapes (Shapes[] Array ) {
     for(int x =0; x<Array.length;x++)//iterates through array
       {
            System.out.println(Array[x].getProperties()); // if it returns a string
            Array[x].getProperties(); //if it goes directly to console
       }
    }
 }
```

2nd way part2:

```
 public void getProperties()
 {
    System.out.println("varProp");
    System.out.println("varProp");
    System.out.println("varProp");
 }
```

Comment: I have been using toString and want to approach it differently. I have seen several ways to use a looping structure that demonstrates polymorphism by calling all of the methods.

Comment: Super seems useless if they all have the same constructors. Can I use for(I=0; I<array.length;i++)

Comment: Polymorphism is demonstrated by calling the toString or getProperties methods as you would have different implemenations.

Comment: Yeah I want printed directly in my main method.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a Shapes class and make abstract and then have all the methods that you need for all your shapes in your super class called Shape, and then when you create a class like Square, or rectangle it can just extend Shape but it doesn't have to be abstract. But the complier will make you implement all the methods that you had in your super class.